# Background and foreground opacity different on the same canvas?

Tags: javascript, css, canvas

I'm trying to overlay part of a page with a triangle. I have an absolutely positioned div that I put some text in. I can display / hide it in response to buttons being clicked. However, when I replace the text with a canvas nested in the div, I'm having trouble with the display. I would like for the canvas background to be transparent but have the triangle be visible, covering part of the page it's overlaying. My stylesheet has visibility none. I've tried a bunch of combinations of opacity, visibility, etc., but so far with no success. I usually end up with the  background (unfilled part) and the triangle showing with the same opacity. Any ideas? Is there a whole better approach?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I answered my own poorly worded question while I was lying wide awake last night. I made the div with the canvas element transparent and that was all it took.